# Cross Site Request Forgery has been found in jquery.js (Included by Wordpress)

Tags: jquery, wordpress, security, csrf, jquery-migrate

I am running a wordpress site for my client. My client had run the security test  (using W3AF) on the website and the report is saying that there are CSRF found in the website for jquery.js and jquery.migrate.min.js. (Those files are included by wordpress)

The report is saying as below:

**Cross Site Request Forgery has been found at: http://foo.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js. This vulnerability was found in the request with id 397.**

**Cross Site Request Forgery has been found at: http://foo.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.form.min.js. This vulnerability was found in the request with id 406**

It is showing in style.css also.

Please guide me with any solution for this.

Comment: Scanning tools always find plenty false positives. It is difficult to see how a GET request to a static script file could ever constitute CSRF.

Comment: You are right bobnice, there are not actual vulnerabilities. But in order to hide those errors from the report is that I hide  to display the version in the jquery.js and other files.

Comment: I'm looking at [the code](https://github.com/andresriancho/w3af/blob/master/w3af/plugins/audit/csrf.py) and this looks like total nonsense. It's going to complain for any URL that doesn't use CSRF parameters with a few pre-determined names—and if `_strict_mode` is on that will even include GET requests for static resources, which is ridiculous. (In a properly-designed app, all GET requests should be idempotent and so need no CSRF protection; including a CSRF token in a query string is a really bad idea and this tool is really bad for encouraging you do that.) Can you turn `_strict_mode` off?

Comment: ...or otherwise configure the tool not to consider URLs that are static resources, like `wp-includes/js/*`? A scanner should be a tool to help you find problems, not a master to obey. If you understand why a finding is rubbish, it's fine to ignore/silence it—better that than do something stupid (like Referrer checking, which it also encourages) just to make the tool shut up. It looks like a [known issue](https://github.com/andresriancho/w3af/issues/120) that this code has problems; I would call it worse than useless.